What are `RuintimeFreezeReason` and `RuntimeHoldReason`?
What are they, and how do we determine their values (based on what)?
What will happen if I left them as Runtime*Reason = ()?
Additionally, I noticed there are MaxFreezes and MaxHolds. Since MaxHolds can now be automatically generated, why can't MaxFreezes be generated in the same way? And how do I know what's the correct value for MaxFreezes?

What are RuntimeFreezeReason and RuntimeHoldReason?
RuntimeHoldReason is a reason for placing a hold on funds and RuntimeFreezeReason is a reason for placing a freeze on funds. I assume you already understand the difference between hold and freeze in Substrate, if not, here is the documentation: https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/frame_support/traits/tokens/fungible/index.html

Every Hold and Freeze is accompanied by a unique Reason, making it clear for each instance what the originating pallet and purpose is. These reasons are amalgomated into a single enum RuntimeHoldReason and RuntimeFreezeReason respectively, when the runtime is compiled.

The definition for these traits can be found here: https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/polkadot_sdk_docs/reference_docs/frame_runtime_types/runtime/index.html
An example code of how to use these Runtime*Reason:
/// A reason for the pallet DPOS placing a hold on funds.
#[pallet::composite_enum]
pub enum HoldReason {
    /// Hold the candidate balance to reserve it for registration to the candidate pool.
    #[codec(index = 0)]
    CandidateBondReserved,
    /// Hold the amount delegated to the candidate
    #[codec(index = 1)]
    DelegateAmountReserved,
}

In your pallet Config trait
type RuntimeHoldReason: From<HoldReason>;

Hence, when you place a hold or freeze on the account fund, you need to declare the Reason behinds the action.
T::NativeBalance::hold(&HoldReason::CandidateBondReserved.into(), &validator, bond)?;

So when you slash the hold amount of the account with a defined Reason, only the hold amount belongs to that reason will be slashed out of the account, other hold amount that has different Reason will not be impacted.
T::NativeBalance::burn_held(
    &HoldReason::CandidateBondReserved.into(),
    &who,
    amount,
    Precision::BestEffort,
    Fortitude::Force,
)?;

Why can't MaxFreezes be generated in the same way?
For the MaxFreezes, it is in a different situation compared to MaxHold, there is an ongoing issue to remove MaxFreezes: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/issues/2997
How do I know what's the correct value for MaxFreezes?
Basically counting how many expected different variants of RuntimeFreezeReason you will have and provide it to the MaxFreezes parameter. For the case above of HoldReason, it would be 2 for the MaxHolds parameter if we still have that. However, you must include the multi-instance pallets and a few other cases mentioned in this PR of MaxHolds removal.
To specify the value of MaxFreezes, we use VariantCountOf which is defined in substrate/frame/support/src/traits/misc.rs
/// Adapter for `Get<u32>` to access `VARIANT_COUNT` from `trait pub trait VariantCount {`.
pub struct VariantCountOf<T: VariantCount>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
impl<T: VariantCount> Get<u32> for VariantCountOf<T> {
    fn get() -> u32 {
        T::VARIANT_COUNT
    }
}

In the runtime, we add:
type MaxFreezes = VariantCountOf<RuntimeFreezeReason>;


How do I know how many variants thati I have? By checking every dep pallet code if there is a FreezeReason?

It is up to your business logic. Like in my case above, I have CandidateBondReserved and DelegateAmountReserved which means 2 variants.

I ask this because there are many pallet that I added before. And during a Substrate upgrade, I'm not sure if they introduced such logic. How do I check that?

After finding the codebase of Polkadot SDK, I think this is what you need to do: type MaxFreezes = VariantCountOf<RuntimeFreezeReason>. The VariantCountOf is defined in substrate/frame/support/src/traits/misc.rs

I have updated the solution above
